# error: `<C as TrieCacheProvider<H>>::Cache<'_>` does not live long enough

Tags: polkadot, parachain, substrate-parachain-template

I'm adding `ping pallet` in the parachain and i'm facing this issue

[image]

Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Use `rustup override set` in the project directory to update your toolchain according to dependencies. make sure to check changes are reflected before compiling by `rustup show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your Cargo.toml file has multiple dependencies. You need to modify your Cargo.toml file to include only the necessary dependencies or remove any duplicate or conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Also check your version of Rust matches the `rustc` version listed for the corresponding release on the Polkadot releases page. `rustup override` may be helpful.