# <C as TrieCacheProvider<H>>::Cache<'_>` does not live long enough

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

I found the exact same first issue [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/error-c-as-triecacheproviderhcache-does-not-live-long-enough) and I checked I don't have any duplicate dependencies. I also try `cargo clean & cargo update` command, nothing changes.

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air MarketplaceMVP_Substrate % cargo build --release
   Compiling sp-state-machine v0.28.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v1.0.0#948fbd2f)
   Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/ganesholi/Developer/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/runtime)
error: `<C as TrieCacheProvider<H>>::Cache<'_>` does not live long enough
   --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/948fbd2/primitives/state-machine/src/trie_backend_essence.rs:305:38
    |
305 |         let cache = cache.as_mut().map(|c| c as _);
    |                                            ^

error: could not compile `sp-state-machine` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/ganesholi/Developer/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/ganesholi/Developer/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-52c2d654e2027d65/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/Users/ganesholi/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2023-01-01-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/ganesholi/Developer/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.68.0-nightly (574b64a97 2022-12-31)


  --- stderr
     Compiling getrandom v0.2.10
     Compiling syn v2.0.29
     Compiling syn v1.0.109
     Compiling memchr v2.5.0
     Compiling generic-array v0.14.7
     Compiling ahash v0.7.6
     Compiling const-oid v0.9.5
     Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
  error: the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.10/src/lib.rs:285:9
      |
  285 | /         compile_error!("the wasm*-unknown-unknown targets are not supported by \
  286 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  287 | |                         For more information see: \
  288 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
     --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.10/src/lib.rs:341:9
      |
  341 |         imp::getrandom_inner(dest)?;
      |         ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
  error: could not compile `getrandom` due to 2 previous errors
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air MarketplaceMVP_Substrate %
```

This is my [github](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/tree/my-lending-branch)
Someone please suggest me why I am getting this issue?

I had the same issue when updating my substrate-contracts-node

```
cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git
```

[image]

Cheers,

Comment: Please ensure to use recent Rust stable compiler and using `--locked` for the `cargo install`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple conflicted `pallet-treasury` in your `Cargo.lock`(seems one from substrate and the other your customize), usually `pallet-treasury` is a low level pallet which is required by other modules like `pallet-bounties`, so you can't just simply replace with same name.

Comment: what might be the solutions then?

Answer (score 0):

Substrate is not yet properly released to crates.io. Doing a `cargo update` could lead to incompatible versions. The versions need to be pinned to a known-good tag for example one of the [monthly ones](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tags).